# Passing all http requests and React Routes through node backend first for session verification and then return path

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm trying to pass all http requests and React Routes through a node backend to verify session.

I am also using webpack-dev-server, so I assume in my dev environment I will need to use the proxy feature.

But once the request hits the node server, I'm not sure how to pass the results back to react front end and proceed with the normal react router page.

Something like:
 1. Click React Router link to /contact

3. /contact route in node verifies session
4. Session is/isn't valid
5. If valid proceed with normal page load
6. If not valid return to homepage and change state.

I assume at least some of this will be done with lifecycle methods?

Is any of this possible without using front end functionality other than react router. I want to make this entirely back end dependent to verify the existing session or generate a new session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React handles all routing on the client side, if you want to access /contact outside your web app you must have something like this:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index');
});
```

If you want to handle a predefined route you can also do this:

```
// Path can be anything you want check in this case any route
app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
  const { token } = req.cookies;
  if (!token) {
    res.status(400).send({ data: 'error' });
  } else {
    // Verifying some token function
    verifyIdToken(token)
      .then((claims) => {
        // Perform some operations or assignments
        req.claims = claims;
        // Countinue
        next();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        res.status(400).send({ data: 'error', message: error });
      });
  }
});
```

But if you want to verify session in the client I suggest making a call to an  '/authenticate' route, then update your state accordingly to your response, for example:

I have a Home component, it can only be visible to logged users, so I created a high order component to wrap it that looks like this:

hoc-admin.js

```js
// Generic validation method
const isEmpty = prop => (
  prop === null ||
  prop === undefined ||
  (prop.hasOwnProperty('length') && prop.length === 0) ||
  (prop.constructor === Object && Object.keys(prop).length === 0)
);

// This receives the props I want to check and the component to render
const userHOC = (props, Comp) => (WrappedComponent) => {
  return class userHOC extends Component {
    render() {
      let valid = false;
      props.map((prop) => {
        valid = this.props && !isEmpty(this.props[prop])
        // You can also check redux state props
        // valid = this.props.common && !isEmpty(this.props.common[prop])
      });
      return valid
        ? (
          <WrappedComponent {...this.props} /> // My wrapped component (Home)
        )
        : (
          <Comp {...this.props} /> // My parameter component (Login)
        )
    }
  };
};

export default userHOC;
```

Then I just need to wrap every component that needs some prop to show, in this case we arre looking for users in my home component so:

```js
import HocUser from '../hoc/hoc-user';

class Home extends Component {
...
}

export default HocUser(['user'], Login)(Home);
``
```